# Not able to open file from properties file in Perl

Tags: perl, properties

I am trying to open a read file path from properties file, but I am unable to do that. However, I have tried doing some hard-coded, it works fine.

```
Error: Could not open file '/home/ad/prod/logs/test.log' 
  No such file or directory at binaryImageTransfer.pl
```

In below code, when I try to use tempVar directly it works. I have also tried printing logFileName. It works

```
my $config = Config::Tiny->new; 
$config = Config::Tiny->read('myconfig_imagetransfer');
$logFileName = $config->{TRUNK}->{LOG_FILE}; 
chomp $logFileName; 
#my $tempVar = '/home/ad/prod/logs/test.log'; 
my $tempVar = $logFileName; 
open($logFile, '>>', $tempVar) or die "Could not open file $tempVar $!"; 


myconfig_imagetransfer 
TRUNK SOURCE_DIR = /home/ad/prod/war 
TARGET_DIR = /app/tomcat6/trunkcurrent/webapps 
LOG_FILE = '/home/ad/prod/logs/test.log'
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single quotes around the value of `LOG_FILE` is unnecessary. Furthermore, in your configure file, 'TRUNK' should be a section name, so try this configure file:

```
[TRUNK]
SOURCE_DIR = /home/ad/prod/war 
TARGET_DIR = /app/tomcat6/trunkcurrent/webapps 
LOG_FILE = /home/ad/prod/logs/test.log
```